# Localhost AJAX request error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, localhost, jsonp

I receive an error when i try to make a AJAX request.
The output is

```
{
    "streams": [
        [],
        { "stream": "stream" },
        { "stream": "hujghg " },
        { "stream": "\/topic\/output.smartlab.550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000_temperature" },
        { "stream": "\/topic\/output.sandbox.68a9c757-435f-4c18-8069-135ccc407e59_temperatura" } 

]}
```

The request code is

```
function initSmartobject(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://127.0.0.1/limpid/php/usersManagement.php?tag=getTopics&id=1",
        dataType: 'jsonp', // Notice! JSONP <-- P (lowercase)
        success:function(json){
            // do stuff with json (in this case an array)
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert('errore');
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            alert(err.Message);
        }
    });
}
```

`err.Message` doesn't return anything

Comment: code seems to be fine

Comment: `alert(error)` and see what you are geting.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.

Comment: Json is invalid because i delete some tests , probably i forgot some curly brackets but i've tested it and it works

Comment: alert (error)Error: jQuery111208490159245722986_1446027357091 was not called

Comment: If the json listed here is the one you actually get from the server, please update the question

Comment: Now the json listed here is correct

Comment: When you use domain in url that mean cross domain request. You must remove your domain from url.